# Vector space over local field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number field and $\frak p$ a place of $K$ and $\frak P$ aplace of $L$ above.

My question: $L$ can be considered as a vector space over $K_\frak p?$

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L$ is an extension of $K$ (extension of number fields).

$L_\mathfrak{P}$ is an extension of $K_\mathfrak{p}$ (extension of local fields).

$\overline{L_\mathfrak{P}} := \mathcal{O}_L / \mathfrak{P}$ is an extension of $\overline{K_\mathfrak{p}} := \mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{p}$ (extension of finite fields).

Finally, $L_\mathfrak{P}$ is an extension of $L$ and $K_\mathfrak{p}$ is an extension of $K$ (completions).  This gives you just one "non-obvious" extension: $L_\mathfrak{P}$ is an extension of $K$.

It's instructive to consider the case $L=K=\mathbb{Q}$.  Then you have the fields $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $\mathbb{F}_p$, and your question, as written, asks if $\mathbb{Q}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.  There is certainly no way to make sense of this, as the former is countable and the latter is uncountable.

Comment: If you start manipulating those expressions to satisfy the vector space axioms, what you'll find is that you've written down the $L$-vector space $K_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_K L$.  This is a commutative ring, but not a field in general.  I would pronounce it "the base change of $K_\mathfrak{p}$ to $L$".

Comment: @Amine This ring will have various interesting properties, probably depending on the splitting/ramification of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $L$.  For example, $\mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ will have varying structure as a ring depending on whether $d$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Answer (score 3):

No, $L$ cannot be considered as a vector space over $K_\mathfrak{p}$, at least not in a way compatible with the $K$-vector space structure on $L$ and $K_\mathfrak{p}$; $L$ is finite-dimensional over $K$ but $K_\mathfrak{p}$ is infinite-dimensional over $K$. Do you mean to ask about $L_\mathfrak{P}$ instead of $L$? In that case the answer is ``yes." The universal property of the completion $K_\mathfrak{p}$ implies that there is a unique continuous ring map $K_\mathfrak{p}\hookrightarrow L_\mathfrak{P}$ compatible with $K\subseteq L$. Via this map, $L_\mathfrak{P}$ becomes a finite extension of $K_\mathfrak{p}$, and in particular a $K_\mathfrak{p}$-vector space.

Comment: if one considers the injection $i : K\hookrightarrow  K_\frak{p}$ and define the laws $ K_\frak{p}$$\times L\longrightarrow L$ by $(x,y)\longrightarrow i(x).y$ ???

Comment: Dear @Amine, $i(x)$ is an element of $K_\mathfrak{p}$, not an element of $L$, so you can't multiply it by elements of $L$.

Comment: yes yes thanks :)